# Create a list of directories from list of paths and create a blank text file in each directory

Tags: bash, shell, python

The input is a list of paths. Everything but the first directory should be ignored / deleted.

For example a text file called dirnames or dirs is input with these 3 lines of text:

```
/how-to-blah-blah/
/how-to-blah-blah-blah/
/how-to-blah-blah-blah/
```

When the script is run, directories and files are created that are named

```
/how-to-blah-blah/file.txt
/how-to-blah-blah-blah/file.txt
/how-to-blah-blah-blah/file.txt
```

OR

INPUT

```
"/d1","d2/subd1/subd2","d3/subder1/","d3/subder1/file.jpg"
```

OUTPUT:

4 directories should be created called d1 d2 and d3 and d4 and there should be a file created under each of these called file.txt

Three attempts. None of them completely work.

**1st attempt**

```
for i in ${a[@]}
do
    folder=`dirname $i`
while [ "${folder:0:1}" = "/" ]
do
    folder=${folder:1}
done
echo -p $folder
done

for i in *
do
    if [ -d $i ]
    then
        touch ./$i/index.html
    fi
done
```

**2nd attempt**

```
import os
from file (replace with actual file name)
with open('directory_list.txt', 'r') as f:
dir_list = f.read().split(',')

for dir_name in dir_list:

dir_name = dir_name.strip().strip('/')

if '/' not in dir_name:
    os.makedirs(dir_name, exist_ok=True)
    open(os.path.join(dir_name, 'blank_file.txt'), 'w').close()
```

**3rd attempt**

```
import os

def create_directories_and_files(directory_list):
    for directory in directory_list:
        if not os.path.exists(directory):
            os.makedirs(directory)
    
        file = os.path.join(directory, "blank_file.txt")
        open(file, 'w').close()


directories = ["dir1", "dir2", "dir3"]
create_directories_and_files(directories)
```

Comment: Your `python` code doesn't "_move a file to a directory_". You say, "_These questions are somewhat close to what I need, but not exactly_", so what do you actually want to achieve here?

Comment: Also, the title of the question is different than the question itself. Do you want to create a blank file in each directory, or copy/move files from one directory to another? Please [edit] your question and clarify exactly what you're trying to do here.

Comment: First, with the input you wrote, could you write exactly what is the expected result? which directories you want to be created, and where the blank files should be created. And also, in `echo -p $folder`, I assume you wanted `mkdir -p $folder`?

Comment: Yes, echo was just for debugging. it should mkdir dirname1 dirname2 and dirname3

Comment: For your example input, `"/dirname1","dirname2/subdomain1/subdomain2","dirname3/subdomain/"` what would you expect to be the result? Please put this into your question so it's easy to see

Comment: The input is a list of paths. Everything but the first directory should be ignored. "/d1","d2/subd1/subd2","d3/subder1/","d3/subder1/file.jpg"

4 directories should be created called d1 d2 and d3 and d4 and there should be a file created under each of these called file.txt

Comment: Did you see the answer I posted? Does it do the job? Your Python code won't help as written. You aren't using the `csv` module.

Comment: I'm a front end web developer trying to broaden my skills.  I get an error on line 3 when I try to run this after I create an input file called dirs with 7.8k directory names.

Comment: It is always good to extend your knowledge. What error is it? Can you update the question?

Comment: (1/3) Your question still doesn't make sense. "_The input is a list of paths. Everything but the first directory should be ignored / deleted._" but then you go on to say that directories should be created for each, manifestly not ignoring everything but the first directory. You then give examples such as  _`/how-to-blah-blah/file.txt`_ and _`/how-to-blah-blah-blah/subdir/file.txt`_. Do you really expect to have the final directory named `file.txt`? But this would then be at odds with another statement that we are to create an empty `file.txt` in each directory.

Comment: (2/3) In your example input file you've a line _`/how-to-blah-blah-blah/subdir/nonexistent.jpg
`_ but how is a program supposed to know it can strip away `nonexistent.jpg` from this line but not strip away `subdir` from the previous line?

Comment: (3/3) Please have a hard think about how you can rewrite your question (and the title) to reflect what you really want

Comment: Actually at the time I wrote this I wasnt sure if I wanted to keep sub directories or not.  That might help explain the nonsensical confusing way I hastily worded it.

Comment: So I'm not sure: Is the input  a space separated list of directories, comma separated list or newline separated list? How do you provide this input? Do you want a script that gets the list of those directories as parameters (`script dir1 dir2...`), gets a name of a file that has the list of directories (`script file_with_dirs`), or gets the list of directories in standard input (`echo dir1 dir2... | script`)? Either way the implementation is going to be very simple, but it just depends on how exactly you want to implement it. Or maybe you don't mind and just want any implementation and format

Comment: Just for example, @ValentinBajrami posted an [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/745232/273579) with a possible solution, getting a list of comma separated directories from a file called dirs.csv. Doesn't this answer your question? If it does, please accept it. If it doesn't, please explain what's missing from his answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do such thing in bash but I am not sure about the reliability of it. One thing you can try is

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS=',' read -ra dirs
  do for dir in "${dirs[@]}"
     do tmp="${dir//\"/}" # Get rid of double quotes
        tmp="${tmp#/*}" # Remove forward slash if it is somewhere in front of the string
        tmp="${tmp%%/*}" # Remove everything after the first `/` including
        mkdir -p "$tmp" && touch "$tmp/emptyfile"
     done
  done < dirs.csv
```

Here we use String Manipulation to do the cutting and squeezing of the strings coming from the csv.

See if this helps

Answer (score 1):

I have written solution in Java. It will read paths from a CSV file using `opencsv` library.

**Example CSV input file:**

[image]

After, loading all paths from file it will remove some unnecessary things:

- double slashes
- dots
- empty strings

Here is my java code:

```
// get user directory in your home pc
    File homeDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));

// read CSV file as input
Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("inputPaths.csv"));

// read back slash also
CSVParser parser = new CSVParser(CSVParser.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR, CSVParser.DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER, '\0', CSVParser.DEFAULT_STRICT_QUOTES);

// skip 1 first line in 2nd parameter
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(reader, 1, parser);

// load everything in CSV file
List<String[]> records = csvReader.readAll();
for (String[] record : records) {
    // replace double slashes from a path
    String newString = record[0].replaceAll("//", "/");
    // split path on forward slashes
    String[] folders = newString.split("/");
    String path = homeDir + "\\direcotories";
    for (String folder : folders) {
        // check if path is not empty and not contains a dot character
        if (!folder.isEmpty() && !folder.contains(".")) {
            path += ("\\" + folder); // concatenate complete path
        }
    }
    File theDir = new File(path);
    try {
        if (theDir.mkdirs()) { // create directories
            File emptyFile = new File(theDir, "\\file.txt");
            if (emptyFile.createNewFile()) { // create an empty file
                System.out.println("File created: " + emptyFile.getPath());
            } else {
                System.out.println("File already created: " + emptyFile.getPath());
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**Output Screenshot:**

[image]

**Created Directories Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Please don't put screenshots to the answers. You need to copy paste the text from the terminal. Also, this is Unix and Linux site, not Windows, so the answer should be specific for Unix/Linux. Lastly, Java is an overkill for this solution, but if you used it, you might also explain how to run this, because it's not a programmer's site and not everyone knows how to compile/run Java code.

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash

file="dirnames"

while read line
do
    while [ "${line:0:1}" = "/" ]
    do
        line=${line:1}
    done
    mkdir -p $line
done < $file

for i in *
do
    if [ -d $i ]
    then
        touch ./$i/file.txt
    fi
done
```

Comment: In your question you said: "Everything but the first directory should be ignored". I don't see this in this answer. You're only removing the leading slash. Also, why separate for two loops? Why not creating the file at the same loop following the directory creation?

Comment: Those are good questions and for some reason it was just easier for me to code it this way.  Performance is not important.  This is easier for me to read than a more concise answer that I can't come up with.